# Spring Kafka consumer: Is there a way to read from multiple partitions using Kafka 0.8?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

This is the scenario:
I know that using latest API related to Spring kafka (like Spring-integration-kafka 2.10) we can do something like:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "id0", topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "SpringKafkaTopic", partitions = { "0" }) })

@KafkaListener(id = "id1", topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "SpringKafkaTopic", partitions = { "1" }) })
```

and with that read from different partitions related to the same kafka topic.

I'm wondering if we can do the same using, for example spring-integration-kafka 1.3.1

I didn't find any tip about how to do that (I'm interesting in the xml version).

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka you can decide from which ***topics*** you want to read,
but we can't decide from which ***partitions*** we want to read, it's up to Kafka to decide that in order to avoid reading the same message more than once.

**Consumers don't share partitions for reading purposes, by Kafka definition.**

If you'll have more consumers than partitions some consumers will stay idle and won't consume from any partition. for example, if we'll have 5 consumers and 4 partitions, 1 consumer will stay idle and won't consume data from kafka broker.

**The actual partition assignment is being done by a kafka broker (the group coordinator) and a leader consumer. we can't control that.**

Comment: I understand your point. What i meant basically is a have. 4 partitions related to one topic. And my consumer is just consuming messages from one partition. Isnt the example that I posted reading from different partitions?

Comment: If you have one consumer and 4 partitions that consumer will consume from all 4 partitions.

Comment: Ok. I just updated the description. If you see the second line says partition 1 and the other one says partition 0. In that case how does that work? I got that from this example: http://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/25/spring-kafka-multi-threaded-message-consumption/

Comment: Again you don't have control over the selection from which partition to read, that is up to Kafka internals only.

Comment: The purpose of partitions is to do scale up, you are trying to achieve something with partitions that originally designed to do with topics

Answer (score 0):

This definition helped me the most:

> In Apache Kafka, the consumer group concept is a way of achieving two
>   things:
>
> Having consumers as part of the same consumer group means providing the “*competing consumers*” pattern with whom the messages
>   from topic partitions are spread across the members of the group. Each
>   consumer receives messages from one or more partitions
>   (“automatically” assigned to it) and the same messages won’t be
>   received by the other consumers (assigned to different partitions). In
>   this way, we can scale the number of the consumers up to the number of
>   the partitions (having one consumer reading only one partition); in
>   this case, a new consumer joining the group will be in an idle state
>   without being assigned to any partition.
>
> Having consumers as part of different consumer groups means providing the “*publish/subscribe*” pattern where the messages from
>   topic partitions are sent to all the consumers across the different
>   groups. It means that inside the same consumer group, we’ll have the
>   rules explained above, but across different groups, the consumers will
>   receive the same messages. It’s useful when the messages inside a
>   topic are of interest for different applications that will process
>   them in different ways. We want all the interested applications to
>   receive all the same messages from the topic.

From here [Don't Use Apache Kafka Consumer Groups the Wrong Way!](https://dzone.com/articles/dont-use-apache-kafka-consumer-groups-the-wrong-wa)